# Form Validation in codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the Below codeigniter code without entering a data in the textbox and submit it .It Should  throw form validation .In my case only form validation is not throwing it is required except email.Pls help me to Solve the issue.
Controller:

```
function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('college_name', 'college_name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Phone Number', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'address', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'trim|required');
         $this->load->helper('date');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('contact_view');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('contact_model');

            if($query = $this->contact_model->create_member())
            {

                $this->load->view('contact_view');  
                    redirect('contact', 'refresh'); 
            }


        }

    }


}
```

View:

```
<?php

echo form_open('contact/create_member');

echo form_input('name', set_value('name', ' Name'));
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', 'Email Address'));
echo form_input('college_name', set_value('college_name', 'college_name'));
echo form_input('address', set_value('address', 'address'));
echo form_input('phone_number', set_value('phone_number', 'phone_number'));
echo form_textarea('message', set_value('message', 'message'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');

?>
```

Comment: Fu Xu is correct, the second value in set_value() is what you want the form field to be prepopulated with - like if you were pulling in values from a database.

Answer (score 1):

in your view, you have set values in those inputs. then the `form validation` will return true if the rule is only `required`. you should not set a default value to those inputs, but use the `placeholder` attribute to display a message while the input field dose not have a value.

and there is another problem in your view. your form didn't closed.

you may add a line `echo form_close();` after `form_submit`

Answer (score 1):

on view you should add this line

```
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

your code

```
echo validation_errors(); // line to display error

echo form_open('contact/create_member');

echo form_input('name', set_value('name', ' Name'));
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', 'Email Address'));
echo form_input('college_name', set_value('college_name', 'college_name'));
echo form_input('address', set_value('address', 'address'));
echo form_input('phone_number', set_value('phone_number', 'phone_number'));
echo form_textarea('message', set_value('message', 'message'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    **admin.php (controller)**

    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Admin extends CI_Controller {



        public function index()
        {

          $this->login_validation();
        }

        public function login_validation()
        {
            $validations = array(

                array(
                        'field' => 'email',
                        'label' => 'Email',
                        'rules' => 'required|trim|valid_email|xss_clean'
                ),

                array(
                        'field' => 'password',
                        'label' => 'Password',
                        'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|xss_clean',
                        'errors' => array(
                            'required' => 'You must provide a %s.'
                        )
                    )


            );


            $this->form_validation->set_rules($validations);


            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
            {

                   $form_fields = array(
                        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                        'remember' => $this->input->post('remember_me')
                   );


                    $this->load->model('admin_login_model');

                    $result = $this->admin_login_model->get_admin_login_data($form_fields);

                    if($result === TRUE){

                       echo 'Login suceess';
                    }
                    else{

                         echo 'Wrong Login Credential';
                         $this->load->view('admin/admin_login_form');
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->load->view('admin/admin_login_form');
            }



        }



    }


**admin_login_form.php (view)**    

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Admin Login</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="<?=site_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" />
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title">Admin Login</div>
                  <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px">
                  <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#forgotbox').show()">Forgot password?</a></div>
               </div>
               <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
                  <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

                  <?php
                     $form_attributes = array(
                        'class' => 'form-horizontal', 
                        'id' => 'loginform',
                        'role' => 'form'
                        );
                     echo form_open('admin/', $form_attributes);

                  ?>
                     <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                       <?php 
                        $email_attributes = array(
                        'id'=>'login-username',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'email',
                        'placeholder' => 'Email',
                        'value'=>set_value('email'),
                        'placeholder'=>'UserName',
                        );
                        echo form_input($email_attributes);
                       ?>                                     
                     </div>
                     <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                     <?php 
                        $password_attributes = array(
                        'id'=>'login-password',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'password',
                        'placeholder' => 'password',
                        'value'=>set_value('password'),
                        'placeholder'=>'Password',
                        );
                        echo form_password($password_attributes);  
                     ?> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                           <label>
                           <?php
                              $checkbox_attributes = array(
                               'name'        => 'remember_me',
                               'id'          => 'login-remember',
                               'value'       => '1',
                               'checked'     => TRUE,
                              );
                              echo form_checkbox($checkbox_attributes);
                           ?>
                             Remember me
                           </label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                      <?php
                              $submit_attributes = array(
                               'name'        => 'submit',
                               'id'          => 'btn-login',
                               'class'       => 'btn btn-success',
                               'value'       => 'Login',
                              );
                             echo form_submit($submit_attributes);
                     ?>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   <?php
                  echo form_close();
                  ?>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Form validation, image upload and captcha using codeigniter libraries**

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Loginmodel');

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'uploadss/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'uploadss/',
            'font_path'     => base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '200',
            'img_height'    => 90,
            'word_length'   => 3,
            'font_size'     => 25
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        // Unset previous captcha and set new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode', $captcha['word']);

        // Pass captcha image to view
        $fetch['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];

        $fetch['data'] = $this->Loginmodel->alldata();
        $this->load->view('login',$fetch);
    }

    public function loginerror()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','first name','required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('companyname', 'Companyname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('designation', 'Designation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('companysize', 'Companysize', 'required|numeric');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
            if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha)
            {
                echo 'Captcha code matched.';

                    $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
                    $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
                    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
                    $email = $this->input->post('email');
                    $password = $this->input->post('password');
                    $companyname = $this->input->post('companyname');
                    $designation = $this->input->post('designation');
                    $companysize = $this->input->post('companysize');

                    $checkmobile = $this->Loginmodel->checkmobile($mobile,$email);

                    if($checkmobile)
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata("danger","Mobile Number or Email exist.....");
                        return redirect('Login/index'); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $insertdata = $this->Loginmodel->insert($fname,$lname,$mobile,$email,$password,$companyname,$designation,$companysize);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Record Inserted");
                        return redirect('Home/indexhome');
                    }   
                // }
                // else
                // {
                //  $this->session->set_flashdata("danger","Please fill all the values properly");
                //  $this->index();
                // }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Captcha code does not match, please try again.';
                $this->index();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("danger","Please fill all the values properly");
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    public function refresh(){
        // Captcha configuration
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'uploadss/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'uploadss/',
            'font_path'     => base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '200',
            'img_height'    => 90,
            'word_length'   => 3,
            'font_size'     => 25
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

        echo $captcha['image'];
    }

    public function upload($id)
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['imagename']['name']))
        {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploadss/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['imagename']['name'];

                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if($this->upload->do_upload('imagename'))
                {
                    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                    $imagename = $uploadData['file_name'];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "not upload";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
        $this->load->view('uploadimage');
    }

    public function uploadimageerror()
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['imagename']['name']))
        {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploadss/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['imagename']['name'];

                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if($this->upload->do_upload('imagename'))
                {
                    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                    $imagename = $uploadData['file_name'];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "not upload";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
    }

    public function deletedata($id)
    {
        $dele = $this->Loginmodel->delete($id);
        return redirect('Login/index');
    }
}
?>
```